# Webstorm Git Install - Error Running Git - Cannot run program "/Applications/GitHub.app": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: webstorm, github-for-mac

Newbie alert.

Just installed Webstorm, now trying to get Git configured properly.

I created an empty project in Webstorm and received the warning "Can't start Git" / Applications/GitHub.app Probably the path to Git is not valid"

When I set the path to GitHub in the Applications folder and try to test it, I get the error message "Cannot run program "/Applications/GitHub.app": error=13, Permission denied"

Any suggestion?

Thanks for any support.

Comment: Is `git` inside your PATH? What does `which git` output?

Comment: which git now has /usr/local/bin/git.    OK, to step back and I just reset this.  Initially, Git was installed into /Users/JeffMMason/Applications/ folder.  I moved it to the /Applications folder, but just moved it back.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Resolved.  Sometimes when I'm taught to fish, it takes me a couple trys.  So I performed the which git again after thinking about it for a while, and copied the location to the field and it works.  So I was confused between the GitHug,app and the actual git executable.  THANKS for the pointer to which git.

Answer (score 5):

in terminal, run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' and then agree to the terms.
reference: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/62745413-Mac-OSX-can-t-start-Git-after-updating-Mac-OS-XCode

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Sometimes when I'm taught to fish, it takes me a couple trys. So I performed the which git again after thinking about it for a while, and copied the location to the field and it works. So I was confused between the GitHug,app and the actual git executable. THANKS for the pointer to which git